# Highcharts. Heat map badly coloured

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to have some cells half empty like here:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/fuw65g95/3/
```

But When there is not a cell on top of one half coloured, it is shown only in one colour: http://jsfiddle.net/fuw65g95/6/

```
series: [{
        name: 'Sales per employee',
        borderWidth: 1,
        data: [  {
 x: 0,
 y: 0,
 value: 90,
 color: {
     linearGradient: {
         x1: 0,
         x2: 0,
         y1: 0,
         y2: 1
     },
     stops: [
         [0, '#000000'],
         [0.49999999, '#000000'],
         [0.5, '#007340'],
         [1, '#007340']
     ]
 }
        }],
```

And where there is one on top, it works fine http://jsfiddle.net/fuw65g95/7/

```
 series: [{
        name: 'Sales per employee',
        borderWidth: 1,
        data: [  { ... }, [0,1,2]],
```

Comment: It's a bug, reported [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3390) - thanks!

Comment: A workaround is having y=0 weight = 65, can I define it in some way when I create the serie?

Comment: What is weight? Could you show that workaround in jsFiddle?

Comment: I meant height sorry, with y=0 and height=50 it works for my case (by default y=-12745 height=25000 is given), of course it depends on your size. My question is, can I define it when I create the serie? https://www.anonimg.com/img/6f335bb5447e9a7c1368b4e886bf5ba9.png

Comment: I would try to play around with `minRange`, see: http://jsfiddle.net/fuw65g95/14/

Comment: No.. its keeps the same y and height, https://www.anonimg.com/img/b54f151f5ba4cef05b1d9e1ef37474ee.png

Comment: Recreate issue on jsFiddle, as you can see, mine example works fine. Another one: http://jsfiddle.net/fuw65g95/16/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fuw65g95/8/ The linear gradient isn't shown, no matther the minRange. The reason it is because of that crazy "height" and "y" it applies.

Comment: Added minRange, and works fine.. see: http://jsfiddle.net/fuw65g95/17/